# How do I setup a server for android phone on my local machine?

Tags: android, mysql, tomcat, servlets, nfc

I am working on a nfc project in which there is a need of client-server model.

The Actual scenario is, when my Tag is tapped, the data in tag should proceed to the server and server then looks-up in database for that particular key data in tag and sends related information back to my android phone as a response.

I have Apache Tomcat, Eclipse Helios and Eclipse Indigo, currently I'm thinking of get it done using servlet? But little confused as I am totally new to this scenario. Kindly guide me.
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd let my phone connect to the wireless router, then setup Apache on my computer and allow the phone to pull pages from Apache server. As long as you are testing there's no big deal which software to use on the server, Tomcat or not, you may easily get away with PHP, CGI or even simple static text pages.

After you setup Apache, use `ifconfig` or `ipconfig` to find out the IP address and then let your phone to access `http://IP_address_you've_just_found/`, this should get you going.

Comment: Thanks Lenik, I had write an android app,in which i required the data stored elsewhere in network.i create a database and server on my local machine.and trying to get data from that server.

Comment: That's perfectly fine. What kind of problems have you encountered?

Comment: I had created a client server model using servlet and database in MS access, and now i want to retrieve the data from my database but dont know how do i get it.